# Response Header Last-Modified not updating

Tags: asp.net, caching, http-headers

I'm having a caching issue with my site. 
I make a change to the js file and publish it to my development environment (unminified at the moment for testing). And I get the stale version of my file.

If I use the Page Speed plugin for Firebug I can see that inside the Response Header for that particular JS file the Last-Modified date says yesterday's date not today's datetime as I might expect.

Also just out of curiousity what is the "Date" field just after the "X-Powered-By"?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` header is the date and time that the response was sent (From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers)).

I hate answering a question with a question, but is it possible you have a caching firewall between you and the web server?

Comment: No caching firewall that I am aware of.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual Last Modified attribute on the server in question and make sure that it _has_ indeed changed there?

Comment: Yes, the file that is on the server contains my changes. :) I've also cleared my browser cache to make sure it wasnt getting cached there as well.